# Data binding using dependency properties

Tags: c#, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am new to C# and playing around with dependency properties. I have a naive scenario where I would like the property of a class to be bind to property  of another class. I want a two way data binding between them.

```
Class1{
        public string Text1
        {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(string), typeof(Class1),
            new PropertyMetadata(true));
 }

Class2{
        public string Text2
        {
        get{;}
        set{;}
        }
}
```

Text1 and Text2 may get updated in different code paths, How do i ensure my Text1 gets updated when Text2 changes and vice versa.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that this cannot be done with value types (int, string etc) but could be done with a reference type such as a class you have created.

Example:
 Class1 firstClass = new Class1(){propertyName = "Value"};
 Class1 secondClass = firstClass;

The value of propertyName variable in secondClass is now the same as that in firstClass. This is because you have two references to the same instance in memory. And if you change it using one reference and call to get the value with the other reference you will see it has changed.

EDIT: You could create a class specifically to hold the properties you wish to share. Then store that class as a property of one of the classes in the code you posted. Then just reference one to the other.

```
`Class1 class1 = new Class1()
 {
     storage = new StorageClass() { MyProperty = "Hello World" }
 };

 Class2 class2 = new Class2() { storage = class1.storage };`
```

Any changes made to one now changes the other.

Comment: So, what would the best way to attain this? I mean property of a class getting updated w.r.t property of another?

Comment: You are right, with basic c# language features this cannot be done. But WPF introduces bindings, which are solely for this purpose. WinForms has also bindings, but I don't know how they work there, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this behavior. The first and easy one is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for Class2 and use Bindings with the Mode set to Two Way. This ensures that the two properties in the instances you bound always have the same Value. Example:

```
class Class1 : DependencyObject {
    public string Text1 {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(string), typeof(Class1),
        new PropertyMetadata(true));
}

class Class2 : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _text2;

    public string Text2 {
        get { return _text2; }
        set {
            if (value == _text2) return;
            _text2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and then setup your binding like this:

```
var class1 = new Class1();
var class2 = new Class2();

var binding = new Binding();
binding.Path=new PropertyPath("Text2");
binding.Source = class2;
binding.Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay;
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger= UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(class1, Class1.TextProperty, binding);
```

---

Another more dirty-ish solution would be to store an Instance of the respective other class beside the properties. In Text2 you can then alter Text1 via the stored instance and Text1 can change Text2 via the OnValueChanged event, whose handler can be set in the Property Metadata. This could look something like here, just assign the instances which should be updated:

```
class Class1 : DependencyObject {
    public Class2 OtherInstance { get; set; }

    public string Text1 {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text1", typeof(string), typeof(Class1),
        new PropertyMetadata(true, (o, args) => ((Class1)o).OtherInstance.Text2 = (string)args.NewValue));
}

class Class2 {
    private string _text2;

    public Class1 OtherInstance { get; set; }

    public string Text2 {
        get { return _text2; }
        set {
            _text2 = value;
            OtherInstance.Text1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```